# Is datetime2 support in MS SQL Server 2014 express

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014-express, datetime2

I'm a little confused on this.  Microsoft seems to advocate the using of datatime2 instead of datetime.  Datetime2 is smaller, and has better resolution and range, but when I go to design my database in SQL 2014 Express, datetime2 is not listed in the Data Type drop down.  Datetime is listed but I actually need the resolution of datetime2.  Is datetime2 not supported in express versions?

Thanks,

Comment: Did you check the documentation? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677335.aspx - says "Starting with 2008". Did you create a database with a compatibility level below 2008 perhaps? Not sure that is even doable in 2014 express though.

Comment: Have you tried creating tables with `create table` statement instead of selecting things in the GUI?

Comment: These kind of things like data types are not different between different editions of SQL Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Karlsen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/267/lasse-v-karlsen)
was pretty much on the mark.  I thought I was running in 2014 but when I checked Management Studio it turned out to be connected to a really old 2005 version.  So the DB was in SQL 2005, where datetime2 was not supported.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!